# Generated exception classes with Axis2

Tags: web-services, exception, code-generation, apache-axis

I have several web services in the same package that throw a custom exception.  The problem is that the generated exception class contains a reference to the web service that generated it, so I can't use the same exception name across multiple web services.  Is there a way to make Axis2 generate the exception classes inside the web service classes, the same way it does for other objects?  I'm using ADB.  I suspect that maybe there's a `-E` parameter, but since those aren't all documented, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a very good guide](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/reference-guide-axis2-code-generation-parameters-part-1) about Axis 2 code-generation parameters. I have used it to a number of tasks like customizing the output packages names (that by default corresponds to the WSDL namespaces).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Doesn't answer my exact question, but still useful.  Axis2 should come with documentation like this.